# $\mathbb R^2$ surface with no image in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> "*It was not immediately appreciated that Gauss' approach allowed mathematicians to define surfaces as regions of the plane with a particular metric that are not to be obtained from surfaces in Euclidean 3-dimensional space. Of course, if one defines a surface as the image of a map from a piece of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$, then of course it is in $\mathbb R^3$. But if one defines a surface as a region of $\mathbb R^2$ with a particular metric, then there may be no surface in $\mathbb R^3$ to which it corresponds. The first person to appreciate this seems to have been Riemann, who also extended this idea to any number of dimensions.* (Quote from *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*)

1. What is an example of that particular metric?
2. Did Riemann conceive of Riemannian geometries initially to eliminate discontinuities (infinities, gaps, imaginary or otherwise undefined values) that resulted when rotating or reflecting a non-euclidean curve about the x or y axis?

Comment: Projective space $P_2$ exists in four dimensions, and can be embedded in $R^3$ only by being self-intersecting.  Called a Steiner surface, I think.  I recall this from Spivak's Differential Geometry Volume I.

Answer (score 1):

If the author had in mind a particular non-embeddable metric on a plane region, it was almost certainly the hyperbolic plane, which may be viewed (among infinitely many other ways) as

- The conformal disk model
  $$
  ds^{2} = \frac{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}{(1 - x^{2} - y^{2})^{2}},\qquad
  x^{2} + y^{2} < 1.
  $$
- The conformal upper half-plane model
  $$
  ds^{2} = \frac{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}{y^{2}},\qquad
  0 < y.
  $$

By a famous theorem of Hilbert, neither immerses isometrically in Euclidean three-space. (Arbitrarily large hyperbolic disks *can* be embedded in Euclidean three-space, however.)

I'm not a historian, but believe Riemann's goal was to frame geometry intrinsically. Gauss had shown that the product of the principal curvatures of a surface in Euclidean three-space (which *a priori* depends on the "extrinsic bending" of the surface) is determined by angular defects in small geodesic triangles (which can be measured without leaving the surface). It's natural to investigate what other geometric aspects of surfaces can be defined and studied intrinsically.

If it matters, in this intrinsic sense we can assert our own universe is *curved* (geodesic triangles can have interior angle different from a straight angle) without there being any higher-dimensional space in which our universe is embedded.